# Android app does not always launch on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using the Android Emulator and the Eclipse ADT. Something odd keeps happening. About 10% of the times I try running the app, it uploads the app to the emulator, installs it, gets success and says starting activity on emulator, but I don't get this line

```
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
```

then nothing else happens and the app doesn't start. Then I just run the app again, it says already installed and it runs perfectly. This happens occasionally, but of course it doesn't cause me any problems, I simply run it again and it works, but I was wondering if this happens to others as well? Is there any solution?

Below is what appears in the console for a fail app launch and a following successful launch, as you can see the `Starting Intent` line is missing in the first and present in the second.

```
[2014-06-05 14:38:13 - TradeApp] ------------------------------
[2014-06-05 14:38:13 - TradeApp] Android Launch!
[2014-06-05 14:38:13 - TradeApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-05 14:38:13 - TradeApp] Performing com.example.tradeapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-05 14:38:13 - TradeApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'GoogleAPI_4.4.2'
[2014-06-05 14:38:13 - TradeApp] Uploading TradeApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-06-05 14:38:17 - TradeApp] Installing TradeApp.apk...
[2014-06-05 14:38:35 - TradeApp] Success!
[2014-06-05 14:38:36 - TradeApp] Starting activity com.example.tradeapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-06-05 14:44:06 - TradeApp] ------------------------------
[2014-06-05 14:44:06 - TradeApp] Android Launch!
[2014-06-05 14:44:06 - TradeApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-06-05 14:44:06 - TradeApp] Performing com.example.tradeapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-06-05 14:44:06 - TradeApp] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'GoogleAPI_4.4.2'
[2014-06-05 14:44:09 - TradeApp] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-06-05 14:44:09 - TradeApp] Starting activity com.example.tradeapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-06-05 14:44:11 - TradeApp] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.tradeapp/.MainActivity }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes some times aplication dont start this problam when come android ddms have error or emulator is timeout when start application 
try use lower API for emulator